# destroy background timer in foreground

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nstimer, background-foreground

I am new in ios.I am doing a app where i have to count time in background but my problem is time do not stop in foreground. Please tell me how to stop background timer in foreground?
Thnx in advnce.

Comment: Please show the code you're using. Do you mean when the app is in the background (suspended)?

Comment: NSTimer *timer =
        [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5
                                target:weakSelf
                              selector:@selector(timerDidFire:)
                              userInfo:nil
                               repeats:NO];

Comment: please specify what you mean with foreground. if with background you mean that your app is suspended than the Timer is suspended as well

Comment: As Argent points out, a timer won't fire in the background. If you were firing a timer every five seconds in the background you would be destroying the battery. What are you really trying to accomplish? Perhaps there is some way to do it with applicationWillEnterForeground and applicationWillEnterBackground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop timer somewhere in the same class:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

[Timer invalidate];
    Timer = nil;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Background process is Start(EnterBackground)!");
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask ;
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
    Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0f target:self  selector:@selector(process)  userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: can u please tell me where should i introduce "Timer"?

Comment: In Appdelegate.h you declare NSTimer *Timer;

Comment: it gives an error --"undeclare identifier"timer". how to over come it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, don't use a timer. Use an `NSDate` to store the start time you're interested in (such as the app going to the background) and then later compare that date to `[NSDate date]` (i.e. the current date) to see how much time has passed.

There is really no good reason to run a timer while the app is in the background.